# agent.transform.position never equals agent.transsform.destination, even though agent stops moving

Tags: unity, c#

I've set my agent destination using this line:

```
selectedGameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = rightClickHit.point - new Vector3(2, 0, 2);
```

Then, I'm checking to see when the agent reaches the destination by this line:

```
if (selectedGameObject.transform.position == rightClickHit.point - new Vector3(2, selectedGameObject.transform.position.y, 2))
```

I've debugged it and know the agent does reach the destination with the offset

[image]

But the condition never resolves to true. Is it possibly off by decimal places beyond 2? The agent does appear to stop moving when it reaches the target offset.

*** EDIT ***
I didn't realize the Debug.Log truncates the float when printing it out. I set the ToString("F6") and have this result:

[image]

*** EDIT ***
Set ToString to "R". Now I see that my agent's y position is not zero, though it says it is in the inspector. I've tried setting it to zero with a

```
selectedGameObject.transform.position -= new Vector3(0,selectedGameObject.transform.position.y, 0);
```

But it doesn't set to zero.

[image]

Go easy on me. It's only my second week of coding.
Tim

Comment: According to [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html), the == operator is supposed to account for small inaccuracies between float comparisons.

Comment: Can you give us the positions of transform.position and rightClickHit.point separately? The == operator has a tolerance of 0.00001 if I recall correctly, so 0.08 vs 0.0 would be more than that tolerated range.

Comment: Edited the post to show the output to 6 decimal places. A float is only good to 6-7 decimal places, correct? These values are exact out to 6 decimals.

Comment: I recommend ToString("R") to get full round-trip precision

Comment: Thanks, I'll run that once to see what it outputs and upload an image.

Comment: I had tried to use something like
if(Vector3.Distance(rightClickHit, selectedGameObject.transform.position)<2)
{
     selectedGameObject.getComponent<NavMeshAgent>().isStopped = true;
}
to stop the agent's movement, but either I'm using the wrong thing or the distance never is < 2.

Comment: If you just want to stop within a distance range, presumably you considered setting [NavMeshAgent.stoppingDistance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-stoppingDistance.html)?

Comment: My guess here is your object has a collider that protrudes below the y=0 level, so whenever the physics/navmesh agent ticks, it lifts itself up slightly above 0 to avoid penetrating the floor. Please don't use "\*\*\*EDIT\*\*\*" headings to separate edits - full edit history is already tracked automatically for anyone who's curious. Instead, integrate your edits into the post as though that information had always been there, so your post reads as a single coherent question, not a conversation or history log.